# Inserting multiple values in mysql using nodejs is causing parsing errors

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I need to insert a record into mysql using nodejs. I am able to insert directly by typing values into the query just fine. I can insert using query + value syntax to concatenate the values but read this leaves open the risk of SQL injection.

```js
        let sql ="INSERT INTO gametypes (strGameType, intTeamSize, intMaxPlayers, intMinPlayers) Values ? ";
        var gametype ="Solo Zonewars";
        var teamSize =1;
        var maxPlayers = 16;
        var minPlayers = 10;
        var values = [gametype, teamSize, maxPlayers, minPlayers];

        console.log("connected as id '" + connection.threadId);
        
        connection.query(sql, values, function(err, result, fields) {
            connection.release();
            if(!err) {
                console.log(result);
            }else console.log(err);
        });
```

Below is the attached error I am getting from mysql. It seems like it is putting extra quotes around the gametype variable and not attempting to insert the rest into the query. Any ideas?
[error from mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABwp8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to not use an array and replace your query by this one

```js
let sql ="INSERT INTO gametypes (strGameType, intTeamSize, intMaxPlayers, intMinPlayers) Values (?, ?, ?, ?) ";
```

then you will pass the values one by one

Answer (score 1):

If you are having 4 value parameters to the query, you should have 4 question marks as well. Try with the first line changed to:

```
let sql ="INSERT INTO gametypes (strGameType, intTeamSize, intMaxPlayers, intMinPlayers) Values (?, ?, ?, ?) ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your values into an array, as this method is intended for inserting multiple rows:

```
   let sql ="INSERT INTO gametypes (strGameType, intTeamSize, intMaxPlayers, intMinPlayers) Values ? ";
        var gametype ="Solo Zonewars";
        var teamSize =1;
        var maxPlayers = 16;
        var minPlayers = 10;
        var values = [
               [gametype, teamSize, maxPlayers, minPlayers]
        ];

    console.log("connected as id '" + connection.threadId);

    connection.query(sql, [values], function(err, result, fields) {
        connection.release();
        if(!err) {
            console.log(result);
        }else console.log(err);
    });
```